# Discord.js v13 | ReactionRole.findOneAndUpdate() does not update data in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord, discord.js

**Code:**

```js
                const role = interaction.options.getRole('role');
                const description = interaction.options.getString('description');
                const emoji = interaction.options.getString('emoji');
                const parsedEmoji = Util.parseEmoji(emoji);

                if (role.position >= interaction.guild.me.roles.highest.position) {
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('RED')
                        .setTitle('Error:')
                        .setDescription(`I can not add roles that are higher than mine`)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter({ text: `Phantom Bot v${config.version}` });
                    
                    return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
                }

                ReactionRole.findOne({ guild_id: interaction.guild.id }, (err, settings) => {
                    if (err) {
                        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor('RED')
                            .setTitle('Error:')
                            .setDescription(`There was an error while adding the reaction role`)
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter({ text: `Phantom Bot v${config.version}` });
                        
                        return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
                    }

                    if (!settings) {
                        new ReactionRole({
                            guild_id: interaction.guild.id,
                            message: 0,
                            roles: {
                                [parsedEmoji.name]: [
                                    role.id,
                                    {
                                        description: description,
                                        id: parsedEmoji.id,
                                        raw: emoji
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }).save();
                    } else {
                        settings.roles[parsedEmoji.name] = [
                            role.id,
                            {
                                description: description,
                                id: parsedEmoji.id,
                                raw: emoji
                            }
                        ]

                        ReactionRole.findOneAndUpdate({ guild_id: interaction.guild.id }, settings);
                    }

                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('PURPLE')
                        .setTitle('Reaction Added:')
                        .setDescription(`Role ${role}\nEmoji: ${emoji}`)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter({ text: `Phantom Bot v${config.version}` });
                    
                    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
                });
```

**Issue:**
For some reason if the settings do exist in the `else` statement, it doesn't actually update it in the Mongoose database. It actually doesn't touch it at all. I've tried awaiting the `ReactionRole.findOneAndUpdate` but I got an error saying I couldn't await it.

How can I fix this?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed buy making the function an async, then it would allow await.